# I Need Install Burg In My Pc And I Have Some problems

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, bootloader, burg

I have some problems:

1. I Got Anger At Ubuntu and uninstalled it (I Have already installed windows 8.1)
2. Now I cant access my hard drive because of my fast boot feature in Windows.

Now I thought of reinstalling Ubuntu to access my hard drive, but while installinG it only shows 3 partitions of Linux I cant find the Windows's partitons,

my fear is that it shows all the space including the space occupied by Windows where I have to install Ubuntu (I mean if I install Ubuntu I am afraid that my Windows data will be deleted.)

I Have a live USB of Ubuntu and I need to install Burg on my PC (please provide me a step-by-step instruction)

If you need any additional info, tell me.

And I have a `efi` file of BURG

Answer (score 0):

I think u should install grub first then boot ubuntu and install burg.
I do that when i install Cent Os and by grub dont see Ubuntu only Windows 8.1 and Centos
there is a Solution for reinstall Grub after that u must install burg from Linux.
[How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) 
I hope its helpful

Comment: I have a Linux live cd, please provide me a step by step tut....please.

Comment: This steps u are running from live cd.
U have installed Ubuntu and Windows? but grub did not see ubuntu ?

Comment: Grub saw ubuntu but i uninstalled it :(, i want BURG because it can boot my windows